# How to connect to the random temporary servers with ssh without password prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I would like to generate few VMs by script and then depending on some variables I would like to connect to them and make changes there (download/untar/run something). Everything automatically from another script.

The VMs are reachable via IP, but the question is how to connect to them with ssh without any password request. The security is not an issue.
The best fro me would be if ssh could take the password from some file. 
Most of answers I found was using sshpass or expect but as I want to be sure that those scripts can be performed from everywhere I don't want to use "non-standard" application.
Any idea?
Thank you!

Comment: Generate a key with ssh-keygen (without password) and write the public part in the `authorized_keys`-file (often: /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys) with the script that generates the VMs. Then you can connect with `ssh -i yourprivatekeyfile user@yourserver`

Answer (score 0):

Create a public key that will be common to these temp vms.
Once the vm is alive, copy the common key to it using ssh-copy-id.

There are tutorials online I'm sure.

Comment: Unfortunately I was trying that, but that doesn't work. If I copy this id to one VM and make template of it and then make copies of it it still gives me "The authenticity of host '<IP>' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"

Comment: Ah, you need to make a script to add the appropriate entry to known hosts. ~/.ssh/known_hosts I think.